# How can I prevent a delay on displaying a "hot" icon when mousing over a "disabled" icon?

Tags: css

I am using the following CSS code to display a "hot" (colored) icon when a user mouses over a "disabled" (grey) icon:

```
.pic a:link { background: url(http://www.mydomain.com/media/disabled/pic.png) top center no-repeat; }
.pic a:hover { background: url(http://www.mydomain.com/media/hot/pic.png) top center no-repeat; }
.pic a:active { background: url(http://www.mydomain.com/media/normal/pic.png) top center no-repeat; }
```

It works fine, but with one annoyance: The first time a user mouses over the "disabled" icon there is a slight delay before the "hot" icon appears. All subsequent mouse overs will show the "hot" icon without a delay. Is there a way I can prevent this delay from occurring on the first mouse over?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue, there are three solutions:

1. Preload the file using JavaScript.
2. Preload the file using another visible element, but hidden with some tricks involving z-ordering.
3. Use CSS Sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: +1 and my $.02 is to go with sprites. It will reduce the total HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use a technique to preload the background image.  The delay you are seeing is caused by the browser not fetching the image until the user hovers over it.

Here's an [article on a couple techniques for doing this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS Sprites is the correct way to solve this. It not only solves this but also speeds up the initial loading of your site by reducing the amount of images to download. Especially useful with mobile clients.